# Flutter TextFormField different font size for first character

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement this view.[image: view]

I got very close except the smaller dollar sign, now I'm using text mask and appending the dollar sign, but of course, it has same font size view rest of the view

[image]

Here is the code

```
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          SizedBox(width: 8),
          IconButton(
            icon: Image.asset("assets/images/minus.png"),
            onPressed: () => {},
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: controller,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: kSecondaryColor),
              decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: ''),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Image.asset("assets/images/plus.png"),
            onPressed: () => {},
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 8),
        ],
      ),
```

Would be easy to do if I can change the font size of the first character of the TextField or maybe I should use different widget for only dollar sign, but I couldn't manage it to place it inside `Expanded`.

`leadingIcon` property of `TextFormField` puts the sign to beginning of the field, so symbol doesn't follow the text it just stays there, so that it didn't work for me.

`prefixText` property is also puts the text far away from actualy numbers like this, if I can fix that, that also works.
[image: sample]

Answer (score 3):

## Update

You need to get rid of `Expanded` as it won't push the prefix widget with your text. There are other ways to achieve the same effect. You can use `Flexible` instead to allow `TextFormField` to be only as big as it needs to be. `InputDecoration` has a `prefix:` property that is not available under the `.collapsed` constructor, so you can remove the border using `InputBorder.none` instead. Overall you need to make the following changes:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    SizedBox(width: 8),

    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () => {},
    ),

    Spacer(), //<-- This is what I've been telling to add

    Flexible( //<-- Change Expanded to Flexible
      child: TextFormField(
        initialValue: '234',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 48,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.purple,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration( //<-- Removed collapsed factory constructor
          border: InputBorder.none, //<-- Use this to remove the border
          prefix: Text( //<-- This is your actual prefix Widget
            "\$",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
     ),

     Spacer(), //<-- This is what I've been telling to add

     IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () => {},
     ),

      SizedBox(width: 8),
    ],
  ),
);
```

---

## This is the final output

[image]

Comment: I'm using textfield not a text

Comment: Update: See the screenshot, prefixIcon has a big margin to text.

Comment: No @EmreAkcan, in the screenshot you used prefixText which is different from prefixIcon. prefixIcon takes a widget argument and can be passed anything for a prefix.

Comment: It produces same thing in screenshot, probably because my textfield is in expanded

Comment: Instead of wrapping it in expanded. Try using spacer widgets before and after. That will push the buttons at the end of the row.

Comment: How can I ensure buttons will have 16dp gap from start & end in that case?

Comment: @EmreAkcan I've changed my answer to handle all your requirements.

Comment: I just ran your code, textfield has fixed height so its not expanding to plus signs

Answer (score 0):

Would wrapping the TextFormField inside a `Row`, along with `Text` widget to hold $ help?
Also take care to put `MainAxisSize.min`, so that both the widgets stay together.

**Update**

Putting up the code, do not wrap `Expanded`, bring the changes inside child of Expanded. I have added 4 comments, which are the changes you will need to bring in.[image]

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          SizedBox(width: 8),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: () => {},
          ),
          Expanded(
//1. Intrinsic height is used to place so that its child ROW doesn't take // the whole height
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Align(
// 2. This alignment will align $ with the bottom of textfield.
                      alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.5),
                      child: Text(
                        "\$",
                        style: TextStyle(
//3. dollar symbol to have a different font size.
                            fontSize: 24,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.blue),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
//4. You might need to change the width here, this is the width available //for TextFormField. Logic used here is
//half of the (available screen width - size of the icons at left n right)
                      width: ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 48) / 2),
                      child: TextFormField(
//               controller: controller,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
//               inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                        // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 48,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.blue),
                        decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: ''),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => {},
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 8),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Everything disappears if I wrap expanded with Row, I need to keep expanded because I want to keep the buttons  at the beginning and at the end

Comment: Thank you, its nearly there, how can I center the textfield? now its aligned to left, I couldn't figure it out